# load stattic resources using tiles3

Tags: spring-mvc, web, web.xml, tiles-3

I am building an web app using Spring MVC3 and Tiles3.. but I am getting some problem for loading static resource.

In **web.xml** I have the following code:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>static-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.app.common.filter.DefaultFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>static-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>enlightened</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>enlightened</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

The **DefaultFilter.java** is like:

```
public class DefaultFilter implements Filter {

    private RequestDispatcher defaultRequestDispatcher;
    public void destroy() {}
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        defaultRequestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.defaultRequestDispatcher = filterConfig.getServletContext()
                .getNamedDispatcher("default");
    }
```

}

And **My Folder structure** is like:

```
WebContent --
          --- css/ all css files
          --- js / all js files
          --- images / all images
          --- jsp /
          -- WEB-INF
index.html
```

first I am getting the index.html correctly: by the link

**http://myserver.com:8080/enlightened/index.html**

in index.html i have:

```
 <table>  
      <tr>  
           <td><a href="home.html">Sign up!</a></td>  
      </tr> 
</table>
```

in my controller I have a method for the RequestMapping = /home

```
@RequestMapping("/home")  
     public String welcome() {  
         System.out.println("/home.htm");
         return "welcome";  
     }
```

but I am not getting the flow in my controller when the

is clicked

Please help..

Comment: what is the error you are getting?, your link is not working.

Comment: Thats a dummy link :) . first time the index.html is working fine, but when i am clicking on <a href="home.html">Sign up!</a> on this link in index.html its showing HTTP Status 404 - /enlightened/home.htm -- The requested resource is not available.

Comment: show your server log, the exception you get, it wont help with your 404 error. also show your tiles.xml file

Comment: request is not reaching to the controller. then only I can do something with the tiles.xml file.